# How to access properties value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, javascript-objects

### Background

I have two objects one which holds image file paths.

```
 var icons = {
            burglary: {
                image: iconBase + "homegardenbusiness.png"
            }
```

And another that holds categories.

```
 function point (cat) {

            this.Category= cat;
}

var point = new point("burglary");
```

I would like to access a particular property of icons depending on a category.

```
var icon = icons[point.Category].image;
```

Full function that is being called below.

```
  //Create and add point to google map.
        function addpoints(point) {
            //debugger;

            var pos = { lat: point.Latitude, lng: point.Longitude };
            var icon = icons[point.Category].image;
            var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                clickable: true
            });
```

### Issue

I don't seem to be able to access the icons object using the above notation. 
Am i doing it the correct way? I get the below error.

> Unable to get property 'icon' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You have `google-maps-api-3` in the tags, are you trying to access a property that you set in an async function?

Comment: It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/c41Ldvc5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```js
var iconBase = "your image base::";

var icons = {
  burglary: {
    image: iconBase + "homegardenbusiness.png"
  }
};

function Point (cat) {
  this.Category = cat;
}

var point = new Point("burglary");

var icon = icons[point.Category].image;
alert(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

The property which contains the image is image not icon.

Change

```
var icon = icons[point.Category].icon;
```

to

```
var icon = icons[point.Category].image;
```

A quick fiddle solves the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/yeshodhan/639zL8oL/

Comment: This is true, but the error says that `icons[point.Category]` is null.

Comment: It was a typo, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you should be referencing

```
var icon = icons[point.Category].image;
```

Not:

```
var icon = icons[point.Category].icon;
```

Comment: The error is complaining about `icons[point.Category]` being `null`.

Comment: It was a typo, apologies